# C++ Voronoi styled tile map

Tags: c++, geometry, sdl-2, voronoi

I am trying to display map with Voronoi styled map tiles.

It is on 2d array, I set some steps to achieve it:

1. Divide 2d array map into equal sized squares (tile).

```
int map_width = 100, map_height = 100,
tile_size = 10;
vector<vector<int>> tile_map; // size 10x10
```

2. Uniformly distribute site(or central) points in tiles

```
vector<pair<int,int>> sites
for (int y = 0; y < tile_map.size(); y++)
 for (int x = 0; x < tile_map[y].size(); x++)
sites.push_back({x*tile_size+(rand()%tile_size(),y*tile_size+(rand()%tile_size()});
```

3. Link site points to other sites in adjacent tiles.
4. Draw perpendicular line of lines formed in step 3.
5. Intersecting point of perpendicular lines is the vertex of voronoi styled polygon.

Here I am stuck with step 4 and 5.

Is there a way to find perpendicular line with 2 given points?

Or is there a better way to design voronoi diagram in c++?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pyzx.png)

Comment: A little unrelated, but if you have a fixed size of your map that is known at compile-time, and it's not excessively large, then you could use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`, as `std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10> tile_map;`. Otherwise, if the size is getting a bit large, or the size is not known until run-time, then initialize the vectors with their size in the definition: `std::vector<std::vector<int>> tile_map(tile_size, std::vector<int>(tile_size));`

Comment: You should use `sites.emplace_back()` to avoid making a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Given 2 points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` gives you a `dx = x2 - x1` and `dy = y2 - y1` and a parametric equation for the line `line(t) = (x1 + t * dx, y1 + t * dy)`.

Constructing a perpendicular line from that is easy. Find the midpoint and rotate the slope by 90°:

```
cx = (x1 + x2) / 2;
cy = (y1 + y2) / 2;
p(t) = (cx + t * dy, cy + t * dx)
```

Finding the intersection of 2 such lines is easy too:

```
p1(t1) = (cx1 + t1 * dy1, cy1 + t1 * dx1)
p2(t2) = (cx2 + t2 * dy2, cy2 + t2 * dx2)
```

The 2 lines intersect when `p1(t1) = p2(t2)`. That gives you 2 equations and 2 unknowns:

```
cx1 + t1 * dy1 == cx2 + t2 * dy2
cy1 + t1 * dx1 == cy2 + t2 * dx2
```

Solve for either `t1` or `t2` and calculate `p1(t1)` or `p2(t2)` at that point.